# Multithreading spark sql jobs always fail

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark application that runs multiple tests against a dataset, the tests are functions that contains spark sql queries like groupBy, filter ...

```
Dataset<Row> dataset = loadDataset();
test1(dataset);
test2(dataset);
test3(dataset);
```

At this point everything works fine, however I can see that the cluster is used about 30%, so to optimize this I thought about parallelizing the tests to run at the same time, to do so I launched each test in a thread:

```
Dataset<Row> dataset = loadDataset();
Thread thread1 = new Thread(()-> test3(dataset));
thread1.start();
Thread thread2 = new Thread(()-> test2(dataset));
thread2.start();
Thread thread3 = new Thread(()-> test1(dataset));
thread3.start();
```

However this is doesn't seems to work because I got some strange error:

```
The currently active SparkContext was created at:

org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:914)
com.test.spark.Loader.loadDataset(Loader.java:96)
com.test.spark.Loader.run(Loader.java:29)
com.test.spark.Main.main(Main.java:15)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$3.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:646)

    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.assertNotStopped(SparkContext.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.broadcast(SparkContext.scala:1485)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVFileFormat.buildReader(CSVFileFormat.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormat$class.buildReaderWithPartitionValues(FileFormat.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.TextBasedFileFormat.buildReaderWithPartitionValues(FileFormat.scala:148)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FileSourceScanExec.inputRDD$lzycompute(DataSourceScanExec.scala:291)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FileSourceScanExec.inputRDD(DataSourceScanExec.scala:289)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FileSourceScanExec.inputRDDs(DataSourceScanExec.scala:309)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FilterExec.inputRDDs(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ProjectExec.inputRDDs(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:42)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec.doExecute(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:386)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.InMemoryRelation.buildBuffers(InMemoryRelation.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.InMemoryRelation.<init>(InMemoryRelation.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.InMemoryRelation$.apply(InMemoryRelation.scala:42)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CacheManager$$anonfun$cacheQuery$1.apply(CacheManager.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CacheManager.writeLock(CacheManager.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CacheManager.cacheQuery(CacheManager.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.persist(Dataset.scala:2514)
    at com.test.spark.Loader.test3(Loader.java:45)
    at com.test.spark.Loader.lambda$run$0(Loader.java:32)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
19/07/13 22:05:08 INFO FileSourceStrategy: Pruning directories with: 
19/07/13 22:05:08 INFO FileSourceStrategy: Post-Scan Filters: isnotnull(Sens#29),(Sens#29 = C)
19/07/13 22:05:08 INFO FileSourceStrategy: Output Data Schema: struct<JournalCode: string, JournalLib: string, EcritureNum: string, EcritureDate: string, CompteNum: string ... 16 more fields>
19/07/13 22:05:08 INFO FileSourceScanExec: Pushed Filters: IsNotNull(Sens),EqualTo(Sens,C)
19/07/13 22:05:08 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 21.213109 ms
Exception in thread "Thread-29" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call methods on a stopped SparkContext.
This stopped SparkContext was created at:

org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:914)
com.test.spark.Loader.loadDataset(Loader.java:96)
com.test.spark.Loader.run(Loader.java:29)
com.test.spark.Main.main(Main.java:15)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$3.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:646)

The currently active SparkContext was created at:

org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:914)
com.test.spark.Loader.loadDataset(Loader.java:96)
com.test.spark.Loader.run(Loader.java:29)
com.test.spark.Main.main(Main.java:15)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$3.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:646)

    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.assertNotStopped(SparkContext.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.broadcast(SparkContext.scala:1485)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVFileFormat.buildReader(CSVFileFormat.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormat$class.buildReaderWithPartitionValues(FileFormat.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.TextBasedFileFormat.buildReaderWithPartitionValues(FileFormat.scala:148)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FileSourceScanExec.inputRDD$lzycompute(DataSourceScanExec.scala:291)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FileSourceScanExec.inputRDD(DataSourceScanExec.scala:289)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FileSourceScanExec.inputRDDs(DataSourceScanExec.scala:309)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FilterExec.inputRDDs(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ProjectExec.inputRDDs(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:42)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec.doExecute(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:386)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.InMemoryRelation.buildBuffers(InMemoryRelation.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.InMemoryRelation.<init>(InMemoryRelation.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.InMemoryRelation$.apply(InMemoryRelation.scala:42)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CacheManager$$anonfun$cacheQuery$1.apply(CacheManager.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CacheManager.writeLock(CacheManager.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CacheManager.cacheQuery(CacheManager.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.persist(Dataset.scala:2514)
    at com.test.spark.Loader.test1(Loader.java:67)
    at com.test.spark.Loader.lambda$run$2(Loader.java:36)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
19/07/13 22:05:08 INFO FileSourceStrategy: Pruning directories with: 
19/07/13 22:05:08 INFO FileSourceStrategy: Post-Scan Filters: 
19/07/13 22:05:08 INFO FileSourceStrategy: Output Data Schema: struct<CompteNum: string>
19/07/13 22:05:08 INFO FileSourceScanExec: Pushed Filters: 
19/07/13 22:05:08 INFO HashAggregateExec: spark.sql.codegen.aggregate.map.twolevel.enable is set to true, but current version of codegened fast hashmap does not support this aggregate.
19/07/13 22:05:08 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 29.090949 ms
19/07/13 22:05:08 INFO HashAggregateExec: spark.sql.codegen.aggregate.map.twolevel.enable is set to true, but current version of codegened fast hashmap does not support this aggregate.
19/07/13 22:05:08 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 20.861207 ms
Exception in thread "Thread-28" org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$TreeNodeException: execute, tree:
Exchange SinglePartition
+- *HashAggregate(keys=[], functions=[partial_count(1)], output=[count#297L])
   +- *HashAggregate(keys=[CompteNum#21], functions=[], output=[])
      +- Exchange hashpartitioning(CompteNum#21, 10)
         +- *HashAggregate(keys=[CompteNum#21], functions=[], output=[CompteNum#21])
            +- *FileScan csv [CompteNum#21] Batched: false, Format: CSV, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[adl://home/home/azhdipaasssh/fecs/Abdennacer/9-5Gb/2019-01-07/FEC/2019-01-07-16..., PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<CompteNum:string>

    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$.attachTree(package.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchange.doExecute(ShuffleExchange.scala:115)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputAdapter.inputRDDs(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:252)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.HashAggregateExec.inputRDDs(HashAggregateExec.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec.doExecute(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:386)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.getByteArrayRdd(SparkPlan.scala:228)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollect(SparkPlan.scala:275)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$count$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2431)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$count$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2430)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$55.apply(Dataset.scala:2838)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:2837)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.count(Dataset.scala:2430)
    at com.test.spark.Loader.test2(Loader.java:60)
    at com.test.spark.Loader.lambda$run$1(Loader.java:34)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$TreeNodeException: execute, tree:
Exchange hashpartitioning(CompteNum#21, 10)
+- *HashAggregate(keys=[CompteNum#21], functions=[], output=[CompteNum#21])
   +- *FileScan csv [CompteNum#21] Batched: false, Format: CSV, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[adl://home/home/azhdipaasssh/fecs/Abdennacer/9-5Gb/2019-01-07/FEC/2019-01-07-16..., PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<CompteNum:string>

    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$.attachTree(package.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchange.doExecute(ShuffleExchange.scala:115)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputAdapter.inputRDDs(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:252)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.HashAggregateExec.inputRDDs(HashAggregateExec.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.HashAggregateExec.inputRDDs(HashAggregateExec.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec.doExecute(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:386)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchange.prepareShuffleDependency(ShuffleExchange.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchange$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(ShuffleExchange.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchange$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(ShuffleExchange.scala:115)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$.attachTree(package.scala:52)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call methods on a stopped SparkContext.
This stopped SparkContext was created at:

org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:914)
com.test.spark.Loader.loadDataset(Loader.java:96)
com.test.spark.Loader.run(Loader.java:29)
com.test.spark.Main.main(Main.java:15)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$3.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:646)

The currently active SparkContext was created at:

org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:914)
com.test.spark.Loader.loadDataset(Loader.java:96)
com.test.spark.Loader.run(Loader.java:29)
com.test.spark.Main.main(Main.java:15)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$3.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:646)

    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.assertNotStopped(SparkContext.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.broadcast(SparkContext.scala:1485)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVFileFormat.buildReader(CSVFileFormat.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormat$class.buildReaderWithPartitionValues(FileFormat.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.TextBasedFileFormat.buildReaderWithPartitionValues(FileFormat.scala:148)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FileSourceScanExec.inputRDD$lzycompute(DataSourceScanExec.scala:291)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FileSourceScanExec.inputRDD(DataSourceScanExec.scala:289)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FileSourceScanExec.inputRDDs(DataSourceScanExec.scala:309)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.HashAggregateExec.inputRDDs(HashAggregateExec.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec.doExecute(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:386)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchange.prepareShuffleDependency(ShuffleExchange.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchange$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(ShuffleExchange.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchange$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(ShuffleExchange.scala:115)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$.attachTree(package.scala:52)
    ... 48 more
19/07/13 22:05:09 INFO YarnAllocator: Driver requested a total number of 0 executor(s).
```

The logs doesn't give much informations, does any body had the same error ?

**UPDATE**

Here's the loadDataset(), I don't think it will add much though:

```
    private Dataset<Row> loadDataset() {
        SparkSession session = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate();
        String path = "/home/user/files/file.txt";
        return session.read().option("header", "true").option("delimiter", "|").csv(path);
    }
```

Comment: please share code of `loadDataset()`

Comment: Also is there any Exception message? Currently you posted only stacktrace.

Comment: Thanks. You're right - it doesn't help much. Is that possible for you to share code of the tests also? Currently all that i see is that SparkContext is getting stopped for some reason and then it says `Cannot call methods on a stopped SparkContext`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was after the execution of each thread, the spark context will reach the end and it will shut down, so to prevent this I added join() for each thread, in this case the main thread will be at a wiating state till all threads are executed:

```
    Thread thread1 = new Thread(()-> test3(dataset));
    thread1.start();
    Thread thread2 = new Thread(()-> test2(dataset));
    thread2.start();
    Thread thread3 = new Thread(()-> test1(dataset));
    thread3.start();

    thread1.join();
    thread2.join();
    thread3.join();
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing that i found [here](http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/Is-spark-context-in-local-mode-thread-safe-td7275.html) is that seems to be required is [this](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/SparkEnv.html):

```
SparkEnv.set(SparkEnv.get)
```

This code shall be executed in **each thread** that uses spark context/session.

Please try it and share your result.

Comment: When you run it in thread - does all threads fail or at least some successfully execute tests?

Comment: It seems that I found the issue, thanks for your help.